# Semantics driving the allowed abstract members in an interface vs an abstract class

Tags: c#, types, interface, abstract-class

I read the below statement in a book "C# in a nutshell" by Joseph Albahari:

> An interface can contain only methods, properties, events and indexers, which *non-coincidentally* are precisely the members of a class that can be abstract.

The thing which got me thinking is why author is saying that it happens so *non-coincidentally* which I think is not the case. I think it is the same factor which drives this possibility in both the cases.

Here is the way I look at it. As far as I know, only following items can be declared as abstract in C#:

1. A Method
2. A Property
3. An Indexer
4. An Event

Now above four things can of course be present in an abstract class as well as an interface. So, this fact is the key driver of what all can be abstract inside an entity be it class or an interface.

Now it seems the author thinks something other way round i.e. the containers (abstract class or an interface) are the driving factor to what they can contain and it just happens non-coincidentally that in the end the kind of abstract members possible at these two places turns out to be the same after their compiler design was finalized.

I want to know if anyone is aware of the varying internal semantics which drive the allowed abstract members inside an interface vs an abstract class. The way I look at it is the fact that only four above type of items can be abstract so the same fact should drive its possibility of existence in a container which can be an interface or an abstract class.

Comment: `...and it just happens non-coincidentally that in the end the kind of abstract members possible at these two places turns out to be the same after their compiler design was finalized. `  I think you're confusing the meaning of *non-coincidentally* with *coincidentally* - these have opposite meanings.  The author is saying that it is exactly *not* a coincidence that interfaces can contain only those members that can be abstract in a class... which, I think, is also what you are saying.

Answer (score 1):

You may think of an interface as an abstract class which contains abstract members only (an abstract class may also contain non-abstract members).

Hence it is not a coincidence but a necessary consequence that the member types which can be abstract in an abstract class are the same as the members types of an interface and vice versa.